# 14.04 on DELL L502X freeze at startup after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, dell, startup, freeze

First i want to apologise for my bad english.

Now straight to my problem.:)

After OS installation I started installing the drivers for GeForce GT540M graphics in my notebook.

I chose the recommended nvidia331 drivers

by using commands

```
 # ubuntu-drivers list
 # ubuntu-drivers devices
 # ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

After system startup. It start hangs on the loading screen.

I tried again to install whole new system and then i've downloaded the package from nvidia "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.67.run" I stopped gdm service and started to instalation with sh command and received the same result.

I sit on this for a few hours and decided to share with you my problem If any of you had a similar problem i'am happy to hear how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who change desktop manager from **lightdm** to **gdm** will no longer be able to install nvidia drivers.

"..
It's also important to note that you need to use LightDM (so this won't work for Ubuntu GNOME users by default because it uses GDM - you'll need to switch to LightDM) and the proprietary Nvidia drivers!
.."

[I found the solution here :)](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html)